# Equation for number of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Not quite sure about the terminology here, but I just used *permutation*. Imagine you have *a* amount of dots and *b* amount of loops, where $a \gt b$. Now imagine you put those loops around the dots, and see how many permutations/combinations you get. Is there an equation to give you the answer if both *a* and *b* are  known? Here are some pictures to illustrate what I mean.
[image]
[image]

Left image: $a=4, b=3$.

Right image: $a=5, b=3$

So, is there an equation where these answers could be attained without drawing them out? (please excuse my bad drawing skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply selecting $b$ dots out of $a$. So number of ways is $$\binom{a}{b}=\dfrac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

where $k!=k\times (k-1)\times \cdots \times2\times1$

Thus for your illustrations $$\binom{4}{3}=\dfrac{4!}{3!1!}=4$$ and $$\binom{5}{3}=\dfrac{5!}{3!2!}=10$$

Comment: Aha I see. If one were to exclude all mirror permutations, would that be all of this, then divided by 2?

Comment: All configurations won't be mirrors. You'll have to explicitly count the mirrors and then divide by two.

Comment: Okay, is there any equation that can do this and also remove the mirrors?

Comment: @A.Kvåle sure, but that is a new question and needs bit more work. The palindromes of two symbols will be mirrors, you'll need to count those.

Comment: Okay, I'll make a new post, but when you say palindromes, what do you mean then? Is that different from mirrors? I might be using the terminology wrong here, but what I mean is if a permutation looks identical to another permutation after being flipped around, it is a mirror. Is that a correct definition?

Comment: Yes we mean same thing here. Palindromes = Mirrors

Comment: Okay I will create a new question then :)

Comment: Your first and third lines are mirrors of each other, so there are $6$ distinct choices in the second case -- $2$ palindromes, oxoxo and xooox, so $2 + (10-2)/2 = 6$ where the $10$ comes from the binomial coefficient as above.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:  $${a \choose b}$$

Read "$a$ choose $b$."  (Look up "combinations.")

Comment: What does that notation mean?