# Number of configurations of dots and loops without mirrors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, palindrome

> The equation for number of ways to put $b$ loops around $b$ of $a$ dots is
> $$a \choose b$$

How can one modify this so that all palindromes/mirrors are excluded?

This is a continuation of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959851/equation-for-number-of-permutations).  Imagine you have $a$ amount of dots and $b$ amount of loops, where $a>b$. Now imagine you put those loops around the dots, and see how many permutations/combinations you get. Is there an equation to give you the answer if both $a$ and $b$ are known? Here is a picture that shows what I mean:
[image]

Here the dots are squares, and the loops are the red squares.

Comment: @cosmo5 Here's the question, do you think I need to elaborate it more?

Comment: A brief explanation with link to previous question is indeed needed.

Comment: @cosmo5 Okay thanks

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to count the number of ways to color $b$ of your $a$ squares red if you _ignore_ all colorings with a mirror symmetry?

Comment: Yes, exactly that @HallaSurvivor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll have to work for odd, even $a,b$ separately.

The mirrors can be counted by looking at one half of the string, since the other half is identical.

For a even, b odd, there won't be any mirrors. So following is enough $$\binom{a}{b}$$

For a even, b even, $a=2n$, $b=2m$ there'll be $m$ loops in each half, hence there'll be $\binom{n}{m}$ mirrors

$$\bigcirc \bullet \bullet \boxed{\bullet \bullet \bigcirc}$$

For a odd, b odd, $a=2n+1$, $b=2m+1$ there'll always be a loop in the center. So no. of mirrors $=\binom{n}{m}$

$$\bullet \bigcirc \bullet \boxed{\bigcirc} \boxed{\bullet \bigcirc \bullet } $$

For a odd, b even, $a=2n+1$, $b=2m$ there'll never be a loop on central dot. So no. of mirrors $=\binom{n}{m}$

$$\bigcirc \bigcirc \bullet \boxed{\bullet} \boxed{\bullet \bigcirc \bigcirc } $$

Desired equation is $$\binom{a}{b} - \binom{n}{m}$$
for three of the cases.

Comment: I'm sorry, could be this is some math lingo I'm missing, but what does "no of mirrors" mean?

Comment: Read "Number of mirrors"

Comment: Aha, perhaps "no." would be better :)