# Combinatorics with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Not a very descriptive title but I'll explain. This is a continutation of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959884/number-of-configurations-of-dots-and-loops-without-mirrors).

[image]

In my last question, I asked for an equation that would give the number of permutations from a given number of "red squares" on top of a given number of "white squares", to take the example in the picture. The equation for the example in the picture is $5 \choose 3$.

(See column to the right)
What if those numbers had to different colors (or more). Basically, they are not just identical, meaning one can have the same sequence BUT it will not count as one permutation. This is what I mean: Without colors, 1,2,3 counts as one permutation. However, if there are two different colors, it suddenly turns into it's own permutation equation: $ k \choose c$, where *c* is the number of colors, and *k* is the number of numbers, which would be 3 in the case of 1,2,3.

However, in my case, one color has different restrictions than the other. Blue can only be found on the numbers 2,3,4. Red can be found on all the numbers, 1,2,3,4,5. That means that 1 and 5 can only be red, whereas 2,3,4 can be both red and blue. How does one account for this in an equation?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for.  Rather than letters, using colors... are you trying to count $\color{red}{123},\color{red}{124},\color{red}{125},\dots,\color{red}{456},\color{blue}{1}\color{red}{23},\color{blue}{1}\color{red}{24},\dots,\color{blue}{4}\color{red}{56},\color{red}{1}\color{blue}{2}\color{red}{3},\dots,\color{blue}{456}$?  If so... then simply choose which numbers they are.  Then, from left to right, choose which color (*letter*) they are... which gives $\binom{n}{k}\cdot c^k$ outcomes for $c$ colors, $n$ numbers, and taking $k$ of them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, however, a criterium is that all colors must be present at all times, or, A and B must both be present at all times. Also, to illustrate what I meant about the restrictions for A, but with colors. Let's say A = blue, and B  = red. Blue can only occupy the middle three squares. Translating that into numbers, means that instead of 1,2,3,4,5 being capable of being blue, ONLY 2,3,4 can be blue. That means that 1,5 can only be red, whereas 2,3,4 can be both red and blue.

Comment: Although I have read (and understood) all of the underlying mathSE links that you cited, I am very confused as to what you are asking here.  I request that you edit your query to make it **impossible** for anyone to be unsure what you are asking.  This is **regardless** of to what extent J Moravitz has correctly interpreted your intent.  Further, it is generally **not a good idea** for the OP to place analysis in a comment.  This means, that when you edit your query, you can also place a *response* to J Moravitz directly into your query.  ...see next comment

Comment: After doing that, you can (for example) leave a *flagging* comment, to J Moravitz.  Something like, "*I have added an Addendum that responds to your comment.*"  Consequently, in addition to my other requests, I also request that you delete the comment/response that you just made to J Moravitz, transplanting your response **directly** into your query.

Comment: It isn't clear how to extend this to more than two colors with regards to the "*only 2,3,4 can be blue*" bit, but for two colors, take care of that by just counting those which are "bad" for the reason that you had blue as the first or last entry.  As for ensuring all colors are present at least once, this is a standard counting problem... counting the number of surjective functions from one set to another... the solution being ${k\brace c}\cdot c!$ where the bracket notation is for stirling numbers of the second kind.  This being quite easy for the case of $c=2$, there being just $2$ invalid

Comment: The final details get more and more bogged down as you add more requirements to what we are counting, so I won't bother giving the final expression, but this should all follow trivially from basic applications of multiplication principle of counting, binomial coefficients, stirling numbers of the second kind, and inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have edited my question :)

Comment: @user2661923 I have edited my question :)

Comment: Thanks for the editing.  I think that I now understand your question.  Basically, I agree with J Moravitz' comments; your current query is very complicated, and I (personally) do not know any elegant way of attacking it.  I did see 2 **possible** typos that (if you agree) you may wish to correct: [1] In the first paragraph following the diagram, at the end of the paragraph, you specified $\binom{3}{5}.$  I suspect that you intended $\binom{5}{3}.$ ...see next comment

Comment: [2] On the first line of the next paragraph, I suspect that "What if those numbers had to different colors" intends "What if those numbers had **two** different colors".

Comment: $\binom{3}{5}$ and $\binom{5}{3}$ are both incorrect.  It is ${3\brace 2}2!=6$ for the number of ways of choosing how to color them such that each color is represented

Comment: @user2661923 Well, I want it to be as general as possible, meaning it can be any amount of colors. However, I chose red and blue as an example. Whether it is a typo or not depends on whether I've understood the equation correctly. The number of red squares should be the top number, as in $3 \choose 5$, or is this wrong, and the number of red squares should be the lower number, as in $5 \choose 3$

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.  Here, $\binom{5}{3}$ ways of selecting which three of the five numbers are used.  $5$, the top number since there are $5$ numbers to choose from, and $3$ the bottom number since we are choosing three of them.  We then color these in ${3\brace 2}2!$ ways, the notation here ${k\brace c}$ denoting the number of ways of breaking $k$ elements into a partition of $c$ unlabeled non-empty sets, and $c!$ denoting the number of ways of labeling those sets.

Comment: Since both of these are necessary steps to describe each outcome we are counting, we multiply the result (*see multiplication principle for more details*), giving $\binom{n}{k}{k\brace c}c!$ as the number of ways to have $n$ numbers, choose $k$ of them, and color those $k$ chosen numbers in $c$ colors with each color represented at least once.  Again, dealing with the "blue can't be used for $1$ or $5$" I suggest removing those from the count via inclusion-exclusion... counting how many *did* have at least one blue in the front and/or back.

Comment: You keep using the word *equation*, A.Kv, for things that are not equations. $5\choose3$ is not an equation – it doesn't have an equals sign in it – it is a *term*, an *expression*, a *number*, but not an equation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, I see how that's wrong, I'm just imagining it in front of an equation sign telling the number of permutations. But yeah, expression is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz How does one factor in the fact that both colors must be present at all times? Also, is "inclusion-exclusion" a principle that will teach me how to exclude all the permutations that violate the restrictions for blue?

Comment: How do you factor in that both colors must be present?  That is factored in by us using stirling numbers of the second kind... it is well known that ${k\brace c}c!$ is the number of surjections from a set with $k$ elements to a set with $c$ elements, i.e. the number of ways of coloring $k$ objects with $c$ colors such that every color appears at least once.  Compare to $c^k$, the number of general functions from a set with $k$ elements to a set with $c$, i.e. the number of ways to color the objects with $c$ colors if we didn't care.

Comment: As for inclusion-exclusion... it is really quite simple... if you want to count the number of good things there are, count the total number of things regardless and then subtract the number of bad things.  Inclusion-exclusion is just the next step past that and reminds you that if there are multiple reasons for things to be bad, subtracting the bad for the one reason and subtracting the bad for the other reason, you might have subtracted the same things more than once... so add back the amount which are bad for both reasons to correct this.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh okay, do you think there is an equation that can factor in this though? I'm just trying to learn this in order to apply it to a situation where the n-value can be pretty big, the k-value can be pretty big and with the whole rainbow of colors. So, I'm looking for some pretty general terms that I can apply to a large amount of variables (I'll be using a sigma function, maybe (or probably) a double sigma function. So, the color blue could only be at 2,3,4. Let's say that the x-value for color blue is 2, since it is excluded from 2 numbers. How could one integrate this x-value?